# How to change country for iOS news feed?

Tags: ipad, internationalization, ios

I'm Australian. I live in Spain. I use my iPad running iOS 9 in English (Australian) because that's my mother tongue. But I haven't lived there for 12 years and I care nothing about Australian sports results and celebrity gossip.

On iOS 9, when I swipe on the iPad home screen from the left, I see some news items. They all come from Australian newspapers and are about things happening in Australia.

How can I change the sources for this news feed to more global sources and items?

EDIT: my iTunes account is for the Spain App Store.

Comment: Wonderful example. I hope there is a way to select this and if not now, it surely will be a feature added at some point. Making iOS personal is clearly Apple's long term aim and people will turn off news if they can't reasonably  figure out how to tune it to their taste and preference.

Comment: Your Apple Store account is Spanish or Australian ? (for example you need an American account if you want the last Apple's features) So the news feed can be linked with your Apple Store account...

Comment: no one actually knows there was a lot of this type of question when iOS 9 was released, still haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if you found your answer regarding your question but you need to change the settings of your iPad 
Settings > Language & Region > Region 
To chose the region that you need/want to get the news feeds from.

That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the country/region for your Apple Account setting.

1. Tap on the `App Store` icon in your `Home Screen`.
2. Tap on `Featured` on the bottom left corner of screen.
3. Scroll all the way to the bottom where your Apple ID info is
4. Tap `View Apple ID`, you may have to enter your password.
5. Once the page loads change your Country/Region to the one you need.